Police officer falls in love with a woman and frames her husband
In November 1992 I was on a Sabena Airlines flight from New York to Brussels, Belgium. I saw a movie that made a very strong impression on me. I am dying to see it again, but have no idea what its title is.
The plot had to do with a police officer visiting a childless couple (I think the seting was somewhere in Europe); fell in love with the woman, consequently hiding drugs somewhere in the house. Authorities come to search the house, incarcerating the husband. The officer then moves on to rape the woman.
There is a scene where the husband speaks with his lawyer in jail.
There was a scene where the couple had sex and someone walked in on them (maybe authorities).
I think there is a scene where the police officer visits the husband in jail.
I remember there is a seen with a pool, where you can see the woman swim. This view is zoomed from above. First seeing a tiny pool with someone swimming in it, then the view gets bigger and bigger.
I remember there is a scene with an ambulance.
They went to visit a children school to lecture the kids about respecting the police.
Hope you can help me locate and name this film.

Sounds like Unlawful Entry from June 1992 with Kurt Russell, Ray Liotta and Madeleine Stowe.

After a break-in at their house, a couple gets help from one of the cops that answered their call. He helps them install the security system, and begins dropping by on short notice and unofficial patrol, and spends a lot of time discussing the couple's problems with the wife. The husband begins wondering if they're getting too much help.

The cop is obsessed with the wife, and later plants cocaine in their house to get the husband arrested and tries to rape her. There are also some scenes in their pool. The movie takes place in LA, though. Here's the trailer:




T-H-A-N-K   Y-O-U!!!!!   This is it. I have been thinking about it for so many years. Gave up on finding it a long time ago. Wow. I was 14 at the time; it made a very strong impression on me. It was the first movie I ever watched (Ultra conservative upbringing). Many many thanks.

If we are already att it; maybe you can help me once more: at around that time, about five months later, I watched a movie (also on a plane) about a person that was frozen then was brought back to life many hundreds of years later. He was found by kids who screwed open the vault in which he was frozen in. Thats all I remember. Thanks!

Well, I have a hunch, but it would be best to put it up as a separate question... (preferably with as many details as possible, like you did in this one)
